# Bootstrap - Form not post/getting

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

so I have this snippet that isn't actually posting the data for me. The login.php definitely works, as all it does is do a `var_dump($_POST);` and I've verified that with Postman.

Help would be appreciated!

```
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="well bs-component">
                <form id="loginForm" class="form-horizontal" action="login.php" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>login</legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                                <button type="submit" id="button_login" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `name` attribute to your input elements, as it is used by form to actually name data to send via `POST` (or any other request type).

Comment: I can't believe that I did that. Thanks, it was a really silly mistake to make.